# Parallel Coordinates Plot in rCharts, how can I reproduce this chart?

Tags: r, data-visualization, rcharts

I am trying to reproduce the code on the page: http://rcharts.io/parcoords/

```
cars <- read.csv('data/cars.csv')
p1 <- rCharts$new()
p1$field('lib', 'parcoords')
p1$set(padding = list(top = 24, left = 0, bottom = 12, right = 200))
p1$set(data = toJSONArray(cars, json = F), 
  colorby = 'economy', 
  range = range(cars$economy),
  colors = c('steelblue', 'brown')
)
p1$print('chart')
```

After downloading the dataset zip ball, unzipping, changing dir, and executing the above code, all I get is

```
<div id = 'chart' class = 'rChart parcoords'></div>
/layouts/chart.html
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

This is supposed to be the result:

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are following the sample code exactly. I would submit an issue on the project's github page https://github.com/rcharts/parcoords

Answer (score 3):

The code in that repo is a bit outdated. Here is a modified version that can be used to reproduce the plot. To use the `parcoords` library for more plots, just place it in a folder where it can be easily accessed and make sure that the `setLib` method links to it correctly.

```
library(downloader)
tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
download(
  url = "https://github.com/rcharts/parcoords/archive/gh-pages.zip",
  tf
)

# unzip to tempdir and set as working directory
td <- tempdir()
unzip(tf, exdir = td)
setwd(file.path(td, "parcoords-gh-pages"))

# read data
cars <- read.csv('data/cars.csv')

# initialize chart and set path to parcoords library
p1 <- rCharts$new()
p1$setLib("libraries/widgets/parcoords")

# add more details to the plot
p1$set(
  padding = list(top = 24, left = 0, bottom = 12, right = 200)
)
p1$set(
  data = toJSONArray(cars, json = F), 
  colorby = 'economy', 
  range = range(cars$economy),
  colors = c('steelblue', 'brown')
)
p1
```

Comment: Superb! Is it possible to add an button for zoom in and zoom out?

Comment: This is merely a wrapper to http://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/. I don't think zoom behavior is supported currently.

Comment: how to embed the chart in Rmarkdown? i try `p1$print('chart2')` and also is it possible to be in iframe? like other `p1$show('iframesrc', cdn = T)`